# Resource and properties file management issue

Tags: java, spring, resources, properties-file

I am trying to learn `Spring`. I have some trouble managing my *resource and properties* file.

This is my `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` file.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.common.controller" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages/messages">
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang">
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="tr">
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

And this is my file descriptor.

[image: file descriptor]

My problem is:

When I delete

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

from `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`, file `header.css` file cannot be loaded.

However not deleting the line prevents me from changing the language. What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map your css, js  and image resources to the default servlet in web.xml by :

```
        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/resources/img/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>

                <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

If this can't help you, could you please provide your app web.xml file content.

P.S. I added [example application](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6u64luyr6ebapn/spring_i18n_example.tar.gz?dl=0) with resources and i18n support. You can check it with:
http://localhost:8080?locale=en

http://localhost:8080?locale=ua

Comment: this absolutely works fine. thanks a lot for your help

Comment: This works but I am not be able use images. I use  

     "<img border="0" alt="English" src="/resources/img/english.png"/>"

to show an image but it is not loaded.

Comment: please, double check your mappings in web.xml and paths, that you are using. I updated my example, so you can refer to it.